# Is MacBook Pro 13 with Retina display Late 2016 MLL42 good for beginner Android/iOS developer?

Tags: macbook

Here are characteristics of the device:

-Intel Core i5 2000 MHz / 13.3" / 2560x1600 / 8Gb / 256Gb SSD  / Intel Iris Graphics 540 / MacOS X

I have no experience working with Macbook, is it good choice for studying developement? Thank you.

Comment: why did the question got voted down?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28552802#28552802) discussion, these specifications appear to be enough for XCode, one of the primary iOS developing applications.

Mac OSX has always been the best platform for developing iOS apps. A late 2016 device should be sufficient to be able to run it, especially with the specs that are shown.

Mostly these apps are just text editors, so these will work well.